# Best way to wireup Prism logger to my own logger

Tags: wpf, prism

I need some hints how to wireup the Prism logger interface (from Prism.Application) to my own logger implementation. Do I need to use a Bootstraper? Only there can I override the "ILoggerFacade CreateLogger()" method? I would like to use the Prism.Application class.

Answer (score 2):

The Prism Logger will be modified / removed in version 8 according to this

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/2058

Answer (score 0):

You should override the `RegisterRequiredTypes` method of your `App` class.

The [default implementation](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/3ab9483145e383d85f69a8660835de4a7da80cdf/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/PrismApplicationBase.cs) maps the `ILoggerFacade` interface to a `TextLogger` implementation:

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ILoggerFacade, TextLogger>();
```

Comment: Cool ... Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Register your logger in your application's `RegisterTypes`.

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ILoggerFacade, MyOwnLogger>();
```

Unless you use a weird container or mix up registration and resolution, the newer registration will overwrite the older one. If you cannot avoid this, replace `RegisterRequiredTypes`, but be careful when (or whether at all) to call `base.RegisterRequiredTypes`.

BTW, the good old bootstrapper is, in fact, preferable to the newfangled `PrismApplication`, because it does not derive from `System.Application` and thus avoids its limitations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!